# Problems comparing strings (arduino)

Tags: c++, string, arduino

I have problems with comparing strings.

I receive from mqtt a number of messages, I want to store the latest value for each topic (key)

I have shown the pertinent parts of my sketch.

```
#define MAX_SENSORS 6
```

// table of topic and value

```
char sensor_data[MAX_SENSORS][2][20];
```

initialize table

```
void init() {
....
  for (int i=0;i<MAX_SENSORS;i++) // initialize table
  {
    strcpy(sensor_data[i][0],"?");
    strcpy(sensor_data[i][1],"");
  }

}
```

Message received here

```
void callback(char* topic, byte* b_payload, unsigned int length) {
  // Convert byte* b_payload to string
  for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    payload[i]=(char)b_payload[i];
  };
  payload[length]='\0';

  for (int i = 0; i < MAX_SENSORS; i++)
  {
```

Why does this (desparate debug) not work?

```
    if (sensor_data[i][0]=="?") { 
      Serial.print("*");
    }
```

Original

```
    if (sensor_data[i][0]==topic) { // Slot matching topic found
      strcpy(sensor_data[i][1],payload);
      Serial.printf(" Slot %d",i); 
      break;
    } else if (sensor_data[i][0]=="?") {  // Empty slot found, store topic here
      strcpy(sensor_data[i][0],topic);
      strcpy(sensor_data[i][1],payload);
      Serial.printf(" New  %d",i); 
      break;
    } 
  }
  Serial.println();
}
```

It all probably originates because I'm confused between strings and char arrays?

**edit**
The assignment

```
  strcpy(sensor_data[i][0],topic);
  strcpy(sensor_data[i][1],payload);
```

seem to assign

```
concat(topic,payload) to sensor_data[i][0].
```

Comment: You may check whether character is '?', using char literal: `sensor_data[i][0][0]=='?'`, but there might be some non '\0' characters later. And to check if its empty string, you may `if ( sensor_data[i][0][0]=='\0' ) {}`

Comment: Is `topic` longer than 19 characters?

Comment: Darn, you are right.

Answer (score 1):

> It all probably originates because I'm confused between strings and
>   char arrays?

Seems like it. C-strings (char* and char[]) are not comparable with `==`, arduino's `String` class is. Either convert the left side of the comparison to `String` or use `strcmp` to compare the strings.

```
if (String(sensor_data[i][0])=="?") { 
if (strcmp(sensor_data[i][0], "?") == 0) {
```

Comment: The first give the error 
"no match for 'operator==' (operand types are 'char [20]' and 'String')"

Comment: Thats interesting, I would've expected an overload for char*. Well, then converting both sides to String it is.

Comment: Actually, it does overload it for char*, but only on the right side unfortunately. So the left side of the comparison must be `String`.

Comment: Ok, the "if (strcmp(sensor_data[i][0], "?") == 0) { " works.

Comment: However there is a problem with strcpy(sensor_data[i][0],topic);
      strcpy(sensor_data[i][1],payload);, see edit above.